# Does anyone know why this code is sending users duplicate emails?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have a stored procedure that is supposed to check db and select all records where sentFlag is No.

Once record(s) found, the stored proc invokes sp_send_dbmail with passed parameters and then sends an email to affected  individuals.

This appears to work.

The issue we are having so far though is that each indivual is receiving duplicate emails.

Any ideas what part of this code could be causing this?

```
 OPEN MAIL_CURSOR

 FETCH MAIL_CURSOR into @mail1, @sender,@content1

 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 BEGIN

    SELECT @email = @email+';'+Email
    FROM GRVRIEVANCES
    WHERE sentFlag = 'No'


EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'Grievances', 
@recipients = @email, 
@subject = 'Account Details',
@body = @content1;


 FETCH MAIL_CURSOR INTO @mail1, @sender, @content1
 END

 CLOSE MAIL_CURSOR
 DEALLOCATE MAIL_CURSOR
 END
```

Comment: Not sure if it's *the* issue but I'd strongly suspect that you shouldn't just be building up more and more email addresses in `@email`, without ever clearing it out.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, no, that's not the issue because once the email is sent out, then sentFlag is updated and changed to `Yes`.

I did show that code because I didn't think it was relevant to the issue.

Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: I reckon Damien is spot on. Run your SP but comment out the `EXEC` and put `PRINT @email`. The results should be pretty illustrative

Comment: gvee: Seems to me you should put this in an answer (with explanation), not a comment.

Comment: @Kenny - it's nothing to do with the `sentFlag`. It's to do with the fact that `@email = @email+...` will always add more onto the existing value in `@email` - so each time through the loop, `@email` is getting longer and longer...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, ok, sorry I misunderstood you.

I will run SpectralGhost's suggestion and see what happens.

I suspect that's what you meant.

Comment: I'm not sure about this.  I wrote myself an email with myself in the to block twice.  I only received one email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set email to an initial value within the loop, does the issue go away? Also, make sure you setting the sentflag to 'yes'.

```
 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
     SET  @email=''

     SELECT @email = @email+';'+Email
```

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I don't know if your suggestion is similar to SpectraGhost's solution.

I tried his and the problem seems to go away, although I am still very confused still.

Answer (score 0):

Back to basics to solve this one.

Start with some debugging:

1. Comment out your `EXEC` part
2. Add `PRINT @email` in the same spot
3. Run the cursor and see the reults, they should be quite enlightening!

Essentially what you're doing is on **every** cursor execution you are building up this big ol' string of email addresses for **all** `GRVRIEVANCES WHERE sentFlag = 'No'`.